# Unix equivalent of PowerShell?

Tags: shell

I've always found it awkward when complex shell commands involve parsing text output with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Basically we're converting structured data into text, then parsing the text again to get back at the structured data.

[PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is a Windows shell which avoids that problem by allowing you to pipe typed objects between shell commands instead of just text.

**Are there any Unix shells which are object-based instead of text-based, like PowerShell?**

Answer (score 25):

No, it is the other way around. There is no spoon^H^H^Hstructured data. There is only text.

A big part of the Unix philosophy is based on the idea of outputting text and accepting text as input. You might want to consider reading "[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/)", which has a nice explanation about this.

Don't get me wrong: I understand your point and I know what you are trying to get at. There are things like the interactive interpreters of Ruby and Python, which can be used as a shell, but they are not as friendly for basic tasks as Bash is. Try and change directory, for example.

Also, using objects in a shell is not all-that. If only your *shell* supports this, on Unix, you would be at a loss. All the standard Unix text manipulation tools would have to be altered, like grep, awk, sed, etc.

I think there has been an attempt to create something like this a few years back, but I can't remember the name and I haven't heard about it in a long time. It's probably not going to take off.

Comment: Interestingly, replacing text streams (or actually, byte streams) by data object streams would not go against the general principles formulated in the book. It even seems to play better with the "rule of representation". It's just that unix has chosen text streams as the interface between programs.

Comment: But by 'data object' do you mean an actual Python / Ruby / C++ object or something like a C struct?

Comment: By data object I mean a collection of name value pairs, where the values can be of some primitive type, another data object, or a list of data objects . Come to think of it, the JSON format could work to implement this on top of text streams, so it's not incompatible with "the unix way". The shell could present output in a friendlier format to the user when it detects JSON. But like you said, tool support would be needed.

Comment: +1 "Do not try to bend the spoon, that's impossible. Instead only try to realize the truth... there is no spoon."  It's not so much text-as-an-interface, but *streams of data* as an interface.  Objects are nice for programming, but sometimes they become a little tiny prison to put your mind into...

Comment: zsh > bash. My opinion but really if you haven't tried zsh you should

Comment: @Wim Coenen 'if you build it they will come'

Comment: @WimCoenen, shipping around "structured data" means everybody and aunt Tillie have to agree what the "structure" is. Even stuff like `ls(1)`. Completely useless.

Comment: @vonbrand PowerShell has done exactly that. It is possible to agree on common property/parameter names. It is impossible to agree on "column position in tables" like ps and ls output. If property/parameter names don't match, you can still always use foreach, just like you have to use awk + xargs in Unix.

Comment: Powershell has no issue communicating with normal text utilities since all of the .NET objects can be serialized as text. It doesn't matter that it "only" deals with objects because strings are one of those objects. And strings can be piped easily to native applications (like `awk`)

Answer (score 10):

There's actually a project called [Pash](http://pash.sourceforge.net/) that aims to implement PowerShell (on top of Mono), but it seems to have stalled.

Comment: unix hackers spend time on microsoft-based projects = that's the ant and the grasshopper all over again

Comment: We're back from the dead: https://github.com/JayBazuzi/Pash, https://twitter.com/PashProject

Answer (score 8):

PowerShell became open-source in 2016. Since then it's been getting more and more multi-platform. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and so are install packages for a number UNIX-like systems.

Answer (score 4):

There is a project, whose goal share similarity with PowerShell: [Hotwire](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/). It combines regular sh  with python scripting and window/graphical environment. You could give it a look.

It's based around [object-oriented pipeline](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/wiki/HotwireArchitecture) that you can extend with your own objects by wrapping existing programs or using Python libraries.

Comment: That's the project I was trying to remember the name off! Last commit in trunk: two years ago...

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could accomplish most of that by writing a bunch of interpreted (or compiled) scripts, then invoking them within the interpreter's shell, which will return or preserve your objects and so on if you want.

You can do this in at least Ruby, Perl, Python, Haskell (e.g., GHCi), JavaScript (e.g., node.js), Matlab, and certainly other languages...

Comment: The pipe being objects mean you can do lazy evaluation etc. So if you are passing a set of file objects down a pipe.. maybe you care about the name, or the modified date, but maybe the content. What data do you pass in JSON? Answer: it depends. If the consumer of the pipe pulls data, it can request the right data. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Another thought three years later: It's possible to represent an object with a text stream using either XML or JSON.  I prefer JSON (simpler), and, indeed there are projects out there to give the classic *NIX utilities JSON support.  For example: https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk

One issue with using an object-type model for classic *NIX programs like AWK is that they really do not have OO support.  For example, while AWK does have associative arrays, the arrays are not multi-dimensional (each element in an AWK array has to be a number or a string; an array is not allowed to be an array object in AWK).

Comment: Clojure offers edn which allows all sorts of typed data to be serialized/deserialized while JSON is limited.

Answer (score 0):

[Nacre.sh](https://nacre.sh) is a shell designed to manipulate objects (JSON) instead of text. For instance, `ls` returns an array of path, `stat` an object containing information about a file, etc.

[image]